# Turning a file into several arrays

Tags: arrays, file, java.util.scanner

I need to read a file with three columns of number sets
1,2,3,4....
severals years
random integers

This is what the file would look like:

```
1  1950  11
2  1950  22
3  1950  65
```

and it needs to output this

```
(1950, 11)
(1950, 22)
(1950, 65)
```

However, the professor says that we should put the all the years into one array and all the integers into another first.

I really struggle with reading from file and I need help!

Comment: [Try to break your task into smaller pieces.](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) What task to do manage (e.g. read a line from the file) and at which task are you stuck (e.g. split that line)?

Comment: What part exactly ae you having trouble with?  Have a look around here on SO, there are literally thousands of questions about Scanner, several of which are actually quite close to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I just can't imagine what the first task would be. I need a way to read every third integer and place it into a array. Once I know that, I cant do that three times making three arrays of 1-40, years, and temperatures. Then I would just make a for loop printing the index of each incrementally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a normal Java `Scanner` calling `nextInt` would trivially parse your input. You could also use `Pattern/Matcher` and use Regular Expressions to parse that input.

Comment: Could you elaborate, we haven't used patterns/matchers yet?

Comment: Learn to do it with the Scanner first. Look at the examples here and elsewhere on the web. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html